# Cart in private browsing mode

Tags: cart

Is there a solution to get the cart works for users browse in private mode?
From what I understood the cart works just if cookies are enabled.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what do mean with "Private Browsing". For example Firefox Private Browsing accepts cookies as usual, it just doesn't save them to hard disk; as soon as you close your browser window they're gone. In other words, Magento works just fine with Private Browsing.

You can turn off cookies completely if that's what you meant. This is however not called private browsing. Magento doesn't work on no-cookies mode.

Comment: As pronto describes from a "normal user" point of view no. The session is lost (because of the deleted cookie) as soon as the browser is closed and therefore the cart - except the user was logged in at any certain point in time.

Comment: It's sort of depends what he meant with "cart". Some people refer Magento as "cart" as well and not just shopping cart.

Comment: Safari, desktop and mobile, doesn't work in private browsing mode, because it doesn't save cookies. I refer to "shopping cart". Maybe I can check if browser saves cookie and if not I can ask to users to exit from private or accept cookies. Thanks for you replies.

Comment: If the browser doesn't save cookies magento forwards you to http://demo.magentocommerce.com/enable-cookies (in your shop). So I don't think you can detect whether a user is in private browsing and will lost his cart. If you have an adult toy page (or something like this), maybe just write a note at the top, so everyone will know? Because this is a widely known problem?

Comment: How can I add a note? Sorry I'm new of the forum.